# Is there a way to print interspersed rows of 2d arrays?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

So, I want to print the first row of the 1st number array and then, the next line the first row of the second array (String array) and so on.

Is there a way to do this?

This is my code:

```java
for (int i = 0; i<=7 ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j <=7 ; j++) {
        System.out.print("|  "+MatrizNumeros[i][j]+"  |");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    for (int k = 0; k <=7 ; k++) {
        System.out.print("|  "+MatrizCaracteres[i][k]+"  |");
        System.out.print(" ");
    }
}
```

And I want the output to look like this:

How the printing should be like:

[image]

Comment: could you share some input data and what should the output be as i did not get what you want 
is this 2 dimension array ?
do you want to print the first element or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code looks fine at a glance, you simply need to add padding before your values and formatting after each loop cycle.

A good way to do it is by creating a method that adds the padding and will help avoid duplicate code:

```
public void printArrayLine(String[][] array, int row){
    //Value for padding (7 characters)
    int padding = 7;
    //Loop through the row
    for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        //Get value
        String value = array[row][x];
        //Calculate padding
        String padding = " ".repeat(padding - value.length());
        //Print pipe, padding and value
        System.out.print("|" + padding + value);
    }
    //Add a "|" the the end of the line and advance to the next line by adding a line separator
    System.out.print("|" + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
```

And you can use the method like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<=7 ; i++) {
    //print a line of dashes "---"
    System.out.print("-".repeat(57));
    //Print a row from each array
    printArrayLine(MatrizNumeros, i);
    printArrayLine(MatrizCaracteres, i);
}
//print the final line of dashes "---"
System.out.print("-".repeat(57));
```

The results should be similar to your image in any console with a monotype font.